# Spacing problem in printing python ceasar cypher

Tags: python

**My problem is with the space in the output**

I am trying to replicate the exact result but for some reason it skips printing a space which then inter-ups another printing. I am not sure how to exactly fix this problem. I was thinking that the problem could possibly be in the coding for the space in the encode and in the decode sections.

**Output i need :**

```
Enter the message: Hello World
Enter the shift: 10
Hello World
Rovvy Gybvn
Hello World
```

**Out put i get**

```
Enter the message:  Hello World
Enter the shift:  10
Hello World
 RovvyGybvn
HelloWorld
```

**The problem is in the spaces**

```
def encode(s, shiftamount):
  result=""
  for x in range(0, len(s)):

    if s[x] == " ":
      print(" ", end="")

    if s[x] in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
      if chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount) > 'Z' : 
        result += chr(ord(s[x]) + (shiftamount - 26)) 

      if chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount) <= 'Z' :
        result += chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount)

    if s[x] in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
      if chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount) > 'z' : 
        result += chr(ord(s[x]) + (shiftamount - 26)) 

      if chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount) <= 'z' :
        result += chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount)
  return result

def decode(result, shiftamount):
  answer=""
  for y in range(0, len(result)):

    if result[y] == " ":
      print(" ", end="")

    if result[y] in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
      if chr(ord(result[y]) - shiftamount) < 'A' : 
        answer += chr(ord(result[y]) + (26 - shiftamount)) 

      if chr(ord(result[y]) - shiftamount) >= 'A' :
        answer += chr(ord(result[y]) - shiftamount)

    if result[y] in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
      if chr(ord(result[y]) - shiftamount) < 'a' : 
        answer += chr(ord(result[y]) + (26 - shiftamount)) 

      if chr(ord(result[y]) - shiftamount) >= 'a' :
        answer += chr(ord(result[y]) - shiftamount)
  return answer


def main():
  s = input("Enter the message: ")
  shiftamount = int(input("Enter the shift: "))
  print(s)
  result=encode(s,shiftamount)
  answer=decode(result,shiftamount)
  print(result)
  print(answer)


########################################################################
###                Do not modify anything below here                 ###
########################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Comment: why is this line there in the decode function:`if result[y] == " ":
      print(" ", end="")`

Comment: @SayandipDutta so it can print a space if there is a space in the result

Comment: You should make use of `elif` statements, and the second nested if statements can be replaced with `else`.

Comment: @AMC i will make sure to do that. Right now i just want to make sure i am getting the result i need. I am having a space issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the `if s['x'] == " ":` condition, you are printing instead of appending to `result` or `answer`. I fixed that, as well as cleaned up your conditionals a bit as suggested by AMC in the comments above.

```
def encode(s, shiftamount):
    result = ""
    for x in range(0, len(s)):

        if s[x] == " ":
            result += " "

        elif s[x] in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
            if chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount) > "Z":
                result += chr(ord(s[x]) + (shiftamount - 26))

            else:
                result += chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount)

        elif s[x] in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            if chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount) > "z":
                result += chr(ord(s[x]) + (shiftamount - 26))

            else:
                result += chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount)
    return result


def decode(result, shiftamount):
    answer = ""
    for y in range(0, len(result)):

        if result[y] == " ":
            answer += " "

        elif result[y] in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
            if chr(ord(result[y]) - shiftamount) < "A":
                answer += chr(ord(result[y]) + (26 - shiftamount))

            else:
                answer += chr(ord(result[y]) - shiftamount)

        elif result[y] in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            if chr(ord(result[y]) - shiftamount) < "a":
                answer += chr(ord(result[y]) + (26 - shiftamount))

            else:
                answer += chr(ord(result[y]) - shiftamount)
    return answer


def main():
    s = input("Enter the message: ")
    shiftamount = int(input("Enter the shift: "))
    print(s)
    result = encode(s, shiftamount)
    answer = decode(result, shiftamount)
    print(result)
    print(answer)


########################################################################
###                Do not modify anything below here                 ###
########################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You could also approach this problem in a bit simpler way by using the `%` modulo operator and using indices in the alphabet strings instead of unicode values. There might be a fancy way to do it without having two strings for upper and lower case also, but I haven't thought of one yet.

Also note that encode and decode are simple inverse operations, so there's no need to define both. In this case I've just changed `decode` to call `encode` with the inverse shift.

```
UPPER_CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
LOWER_CHARS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
NUM_CHARS = 26

def encode(s, shift):
    result = ""
    for c in s:
        if c == " ":
            result += c
        elif c in UPPER_CHARS:
            result += UPPER_CHARS[(UPPER_CHARS.index(c) + shift) % NUM_CHARS]
        elif c in LOWER_CHARS:
            result += LOWER_CHARS[(LOWER_CHARS.index(c) + shift) % NUM_CHARS]
    return result

def decode(s, shift):
    return encode(s, shift * -1)

def main():
    s = input("Enter the message: ")
    shift = int(input("Enter the shift: "))
    print(s)
    result = encode(s, shift)
    answer = decode(result, shift)
    print(result)
    print(answer)


########################################################################
###                Do not modify anything below here                 ###
########################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks. So the problem was that i was printing instead of giving the answer to the variable right?  Thank you

Comment: Something which could help clean up the code a bit more, and reduce the risk of bugs, is using the `string` module instead of defining `UPPER_CHARS` and `LOWER_CHARS` manually.